# Active learning with Fisher information matrix for regression with vector output

Tags: regression, machine-learning, neural-networks, active-learning

I am trying to enhance the learning capabilities of my regression task with the help of active learning. I  decided to use variance reduction using the Fisher information matrix as a query strategy as explained in Settles' popular survey "Active learning literature survey, 2010" ([https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~10701/slides/Settles_notes.pdf](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7E10701/slides/Settles_notes.pdf)). According to it the output variance of an input x can be approximated by

[image]

where F is the Fisher information matrix.

It appears like in this equation y is expected to be a scalar output. I am working with a neural network that has 3 output nodes and I am not sure if the equation can still be applied without modification. Of course I would get a covariance matrix instead of a scalar variance.

Unfortunately I could not find any literature regarding active learning using the Fisher information matrix for regression tasks with multiple outputs.

Can I still use this equation for estimating the output variance of my inputs? Is there any literature that goes into more detail regarding my problem?

Comment: I believe you're correct in your remarks about a *covariance matrix*. Reasoning purely from linear algebra, a *matrix* of partial derivatives may replace the left and right factors in the middle portion. Caveat: I have not looked into the details of your application, I'm just pointing out how thinking about matrix products can allow you to generalize.

Comment: Thanks! That gives me more confidence in the results I'm getting!